# Excel and a multivalued dimension using a bridge table

Tags: excel, data-warehouse

I query a datarehouse database (relational database) that uses a bridge table to model multivalued dimension. I tried to query it from Excel but I get wrong results.

This is what I have / do:

Datawarehouse: Basically there are users and each user can speak one or more languages - multivalued dimension. In the below SQL, there's Johnny who speak English and Cathleen who speaks English, French, Spanish and Italian.

```
create table dbo.Dimension_Languages(
    LanguageID int primary key
    ,LanguageName varchar(256)
    --,LanguageGradeComment varchar(max)
);
go

create table dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge1(
    LanguageGroupID int primary key
);
go

create table dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge2(
    LanguageGroupID int foreign key references dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge1(LanguageGroupID)
    ,LanguageID int foreign key references dbo.Dimension_Languages(LanguageID)
);
go

create table dbo.Dimension_User(
    UserID int primary key
    ,UserName varchar(256)
);
go

create table dbo.Fact_User(
    UserID int foreign key references dbo.Dimension_User(UserID)
    ,LanguageGroupID int foreign key references dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge1(LanguageGroupID)
);
go

insert into dbo.Dimension_Languages values(1, 'English');
insert into dbo.Dimension_Languages values(2, 'French');
insert into dbo.Dimension_Languages values(3, 'Spanish');
insert into dbo.Dimension_Languages values(4, 'Italian');

insert into dbo.Dimension_User values(1, 'Johnny');
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge1 values(1);
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge2 values(1, 1);
insert into dbo.Fact_User values(1, 1);

insert into dbo.Dimension_User values(2, 'Cathleen');
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge1 values(2);
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge2 values(2, 1);
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge2 values(2, 2);
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge2 values(2, 3);
insert into dbo.Dimension_LanguageBridge2 values(2, 4);
insert into dbo.Fact_User values(2, 2);
```

In Excel 2013, I choose Data / From other sources / From SQL Server / ... / I choose all the tables above / and I choose to create PivotTable. I add UserName column into the PivotTable rows and LanguageName into filters. I choose French in the filter and Excel shows Cathleen and Johnny but Johnny doesn't speak French. I want the PivotTable to show only Cathleen because only Cathleen speaks French.

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the pivot table is somehow performing a crossjoin since there is no link between the Languages and User dimensions(Fk constraint..), the link is in the fact table, It's rather a hint than a direct answer, that's what I understood from your question, so good luck.